# How to confirm that a file has copied to a new disk without any errors?

Tags: macos, filesystem

I'd like to copy files from one external drive to a network connected drive.
I want to make sure that there are no errors.

I know of MD5 hash files that I see for large single files that are download from the internet. I also know that I can use the terminal to 'diff' the two sets of files.

However, I'm looking for a piece of software that could confirm that all the files in the file structure have been copied by the finder completely, or a piece of software that would do the copying for me and confirm that all the bits are exactly the same.

The files are video related - and are often over a TB in size (not in one file - complex multi-folder nested files)

I'm fine if there is a terminal command that can do the copy and compare for me as well. (although being able to see the amount of time left on a copy is a very nice feature... additionally, I want to make sure I get ALL of the file - resource forks and all)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> or a piece of software that would do the copying for me and confirm that all the bits are exactly the same.

This is what [rsync](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) does. It can copy one file, entire trees of files, just about anything really. And it does it with a reliable algorithm. At the end of an rsync you can be confident the sink got exactly what you sent it from the source.

There's a GUI for rsync called [arRsync](http://arrsync.sourceforge.net/) that can make working with it a little friendlier, though it doesn't work for rsync-over-ssh calls.

The other advantage to rsync is it can do resume-on-interrupt copying. Particularly nice if you're copying lots of files or even big files over networks that are less than reliable.

If you're copying a local drive and a network that are both available to the same Mac you can do:

```
rsync -avz /Volumes/LocallyAttachedDrive/path/to/big-movie.mov /Volumes/RemoteShare/path/
```

And you're all done.

If it's a directory (which bundles like `.app` are) you can do a complete, recursive copy with:

```
rsync -avz /Volumes/LocallyAttachedDrive/path/to/my-bundle.app /Volumes/RemoteShare/path/
```

If you don't have Finder/Bonjour-level access to the sink you can do rsync-over-ssh:

```
rsync -avz /Volumes/LocallyAttachedDrive/path/to/my-bundle.app remoteuser@remotehost:/Volumes/RemoteShare/path/
```

A shared key can be generated so you don't have to enter a password if you like.

Edit: you can use `rsync` to verify if two trees are the same with the `--dry-run/-n` option. If I have the source tree `/Volumes/dir` and I've copied it to `/Volumes/ConnectedDrive/dir` I can compare them with:

```
rsync -acvn /Volumes/dir /Volumes/ConnectedDrive/
```

The output will tell me if any files need to be copied to the sink in order to make the sink equal the source.

For example, if I sync'ed two trees:

```
> rsync -avz ./8779 ./a/
building file list ... done
8779/
8779/.DS_Store
8779/logs/
8779/logs/MasterLog.txt
8779/logs/StartLog.txt

sent 893980 bytes  received 98 bytes  596052.00 bytes/sec
total size is 10034671  speedup is 11.22
```

Comparing them for equality should yield no operations required:

```
> rsync -acvn ./8779 ./a/
building file list ... done

sent 213 bytes  received 20 bytes  155.33 bytes/sec
total size is 10034671  speedup is 43067.26
```

If sink was slightly different we'd see output like this:

```
> echo foo >> a/8779/logs/MasterLog.txt 

> rsync -acvn ./8779 ./a/              
building file list ... done
8779/logs/MasterLog.txt

sent 219 bytes  received 26 bytes  490.00 bytes/sec
total size is 10034671  speedup is 40957.84
```

Now we know the `MasterLog.txt` file isn't the same.

Comment: Thanks Ian, am I understanding it correctly that I could run rsync -vcn /Volumes/dir /Volumes/ConnectedServer/dir to have it give me a report that would say if any of the files are 'corrupt'? (If I'd copied some with the Finder already?)

Comment: Close. `/` matter in rsync. Try:

`rsync -avcn /Volumes/dir /Volumes/ConnectedServer/`

That should do the trick. I'll expand my answer with more details.

Comment: Thanks for the extended explanation! That is very clear. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

```
md5 -r file1 file2
```

will print the hashes of both files so you can eyeball-compare them.  The -r flag prints the hashes first (rather than filename first) so the hashes line up with each other at the left margin - makes it easier to visually compare.

Comment: MD5 has been broken, I suggest replacing it with `shasum -a 256 /path/to/file`

Comment: MD5 is only broken for cryptographic use. As long as there is no threat model where an attacker is trying to modify a file without it being detected, MD5 is fine to use here.

Answer (score 0):

I'd stick with MD5 if you need absolute verification that the files are the same. You could write a small bash script to recurse the directories and generate / check the hash for each file.